# Java threads migration between dual socket processor

Tags: java, multithreading, numa

I am performing a study related to NUMA (non-uniform memory access) using an multi-threaded code using Java Threads (Java 8) running on a **Dual processor**: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz:

http://ark.intel.com/products/75269/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2650-v2-20M-Cache-2_60-GHz

So in terms of computer architecture i have two of these processors configured as two NUMA Nodes.
It is been quite difficult to understand where the threads of my program are mapped to physical cores. In order to draw some conclusions i need a way to understand if the threads of my program suffers of migration phenomenon between cores or between sockets during the execution.

Any suggestions? Thanks for you help.

Comment: The process of mapping threads to CPU cores depends on the OS. (Which is not tagged)

Answer (score 2):

Java Thread objects delegate to the OS's thread management system, so the exact behavior depends on the OS. Additionally, the OS does not typically "map" a thread to a core, which would make inefficient use of the processor. I can't say what is happening in your case, but I expect that it is complex.